# Descargar un archivo desde una URL y guardarlo en la carpeta download de la memoria interna

Tags: android

estoy haciendo pruebas con un ejemplo sobre descargar archivos desde una url y grabarlo en la memoria interna, aparentemente funciona bien, el código consigue enlazar con la url y leer el fichero pero no consigo que me lo guarde en la memoria interna, a ver si alguien puede decirme el procedimiento correcto para conseguir guardarlo en la memoria interna del dispositivo.

Saludos y gracias anticipadas.

aquí tenéis el código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
    new Thread ( new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://www.videotutoriales.es/android-xml/cursos.xml");
                //establecemos la conexión con el destino
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
                //establecemos el método jet para nuestra conexión
                //el método setdooutput es necesario para este tipo de conexiones
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod ( "GET" );
                urlConnection.setDoOutput ( true );
                //por último establecemos nuestra conexión y cruzamos los dedos 
                urlConnection.connect ();
                File file = new File(getFilesDir(),"cursos.xml");
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream ( file );
                //leemos los datos desde la url
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream ();
                int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength ();
                int downloadedSize = 0;
                //creamos un buffer y una variable para ir almacenando el
                //tamaño temporal de este
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;
                while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read ( buffer )) > 0) {

                    fileOutput.write ( buffer, 0, bufferLength );
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                }
                fileOutput.close ();
                inputStream.close ();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }

        }
    } ).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes quiero comentarte que el directorio `Downloads` en realidad se encuentra en el directorio de almacenamiento Externo, puedes obtener el path mediante :

```
String directorioDownloads = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

---

Para definir el directorio de almacenamiento interno, en lugar de definir el directorio de almacenamiento externo:

```
File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"ejemplo.txt");
```

usa [**getFilesDir()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) para guardarlo en la memoria interna:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(),"ejemplo.txt");
```

> [**getFilesDir()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) Devuelve la ruta absoluta al directorio en el
>   sistema de archivos.

Comment: Y si el dispositivo no lleva tarjeta SD ?

Comment: la SD Card es para almacenamiento externo, tu deseas realizarlo en el interno y esto se realiza mediante getFilesDir().

Answer (score 0):

Has comprobado los permisos en el Manifest?

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Para guardarlo en la memoria interna yo te lo veo bien.
Si quieres, prueba este metodo que tambien encontre yo por aqui...

```
public void downloadFiles(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtension, String destinationDirectory, String url){
    DownloadManager downloadManager=(DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request=new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,destinationDirectory,fileName+fileExtension);

    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```